# Error in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My google apps script is getting the error below. I've been running it for a few weeks and it's been working just fine, but last night it started giving these errors. I didn't change anything in the script or spreadsheet, so I'm pretty sure it's a problem in Google's infrastructures. Can someone help me to fix this problem? Thank you.

======================

Your script, Test Script, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

The script is used by the document Script test 2.

Summary:

Error Message   Count

Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code")  4
We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 16, file "Code")   3
Details:

Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End

9/6/16 8:00 AM  runAll  Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code")  time-based  9/6/16 8:02 AM
9/6/16 8:02 AM  runAll  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 16, file "Code")   time-based  9/6/16 8:03 AM
9/6/16 8:05 AM  runAll  Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code")  time-based  9/6/16 8:06 AM
9/6/16 8:04 AM  runAll  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 16, file "Code")   time-based  9/6/16 8:07 AM
9/6/16 8:07 AM  runAll  Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code")  time-based  9/6/16 8:10 AM
9/6/16 8:13 AM  runAll  We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 16, file "Code")   time-based  9/6/16 8:14 AM
9/6/16 8:14 AM  runAll  Too many simultaneous invocations: Spreadsheets (line 22, file "Code")  time-based  9/6/16 8:17 AM
Sincerely,

Google Apps Script

Need help? Visit the Google Apps Script documentation. Please do not reply to this message. (c) 2016 Google

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Comment: Issues with Google Apps Script infraestructure should be reported to: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a similar problem before with time-triggered scripts. When I was looping through many items in Google Drive, it seemed to throw this type of error when it was going through too many heavy calls too quickly.

Interesting that it started happening after working correctly for weeks.

I don't know any of your original code, but if it involves fast/intense/numerous loops, try putting a delay every few iterations. Maybe once every 25 loops if there are hundreds of iterations, or a small delay at the end of each loop if there aren't so many.

See if slowing down the code a little bit helps. It's dirty, but it was the only reliable method which worked for me. Otherwise, try optimizing your code to make less calls?